# documentation on the "V" label for variables

Tags: autohotkey

Could someone please point me to the AutoHotKey documentation describing the meaning and use of the `v` label prefixing variables in a script?  For example:
`Gui, Add, Text, vErrorFld w230 R1 X20 Y70`
... the `v` prefixing `ErrorFld`.  I really have searched hard but I can't find any descriptive explanation of this "label", unlike the `g` label.

Answer (score 1):

It [associates a variable](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#var) with the gui control.
The variable can be used to identify the gui control, or to receive input from from the gui control. E.g. in the case of an edit box the variable would contain the text the user wrote into the edit box.

In your case, the text control, the associated variable is just used to identify the control.
So you can use e.g. `GuiControl`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControl.htm)</sup> to edit the text control easily.